# Cannot read jenkins maven dependencies

Tags: maven, jenkins, dependencies

I am trying to get this demo application up and running on my machine:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/cli-channel-demo

I have this in my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cli-channel-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>cli-channel-demo</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
            <url>http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.main</groupId> 
            <artifactId>cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.415</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

But I get this error:

```
The POM for org.jenkins-ci.main:cli:jar:1.415 is missing, no dependency information available
```

even though the dependency is located right here:

http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/org/jenkins-ci/main/cli/1.415/

and I have this in my pom:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
        <url>http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Why can't maven resolve this dependency on my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine on my machine. I think you need to supply some more details of your error.

Common issues are:

- Network proxy denying direct access to internet
- Mirror configuration pointing builds at a local Maven repository

See the [Maven settings reference](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) for more details on how these issues could be fixed.